# Continuous Integral over $[a,b] = [-10,10]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, continuity

> Suppose $f,g$ are continuous on $[-10,10]$ and
>           \begin{align*}
>         \int_{-10}^{10}f(x)h(x)\,dx = \int_{-10}^{10}g(x)h(x)\,dx \quad \textrm{for any}\,h\,\textrm{integrable on}\,[-10,10]
>     \end{align*}
>   Show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in[-10,10]$

I've gotten as far as rearranging the integral to
        \begin{align*}
        \int_{-10}^{10}h(x)(f(x)-g(x))\,dx = 0
    \end{align*}
But is there one more assumption that can be made?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Then you know that$$\int_{-10}^{10}\bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr)^2\,\mathrm dx=0.$$Since $f-g$ is continuous, it follows from this that it is the null function.